# Is relation $R={(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10)}$ transitive if $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ subset of naturals?

Tags: relations

I know that at first this sounds like a stupid question but I'm not sure about its meaning.

Transitivity states that whenever $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$, then $(a,c) \in R$, where R is the relation.

Take for example the elements $a=1, b=2$. Now, $1$ is in relation to $2$, so to test for transitivity I'd need a pair $(2,c) \in R$. However, I don't have any pair that satisfies that condition so I'm not sure how to proceed from here. If I had a pair $(2,c)$, I could easily check whether transitivity holds for $1$ if simply $1Rc$. However, since I can't do that, I'm not sure if this relation is transitive or not.

Comment: Since $(2,c)\in R$ never holds, $$(1,2)\in R\text{ and }(2,c)\in R\implies (1,c)\in R$$
is true for all $c$.

Comment: @Surb so generalizing it for all elements of $A$, $R$ is transitive?

Comment: Yes it is transitive.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."